# Ruby- get a xml node value

Tags: ruby, xml

can someone help me in extracting the node value for the element "Name".

**Type 1:** I am able to extract the "name" value for the below xml by using the below code

```
<Element>
   <Details>
      <ID>20367</ID>      
      <Name>Ram</Name>
      <Name>Sam</Name>
   </Details>
</Element>


doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)    
values = doc.xpath('//Name').map{ |node| node.text}.join ','
puts values
```

*Output:* Ram,Sam

**Type 2:** Now, I am need to get the same formatted output for the below xml, How can I get it

```
<Response xmlns="http://abc.def" xmlns:i="http://www.org">
   <Name>Ram</Name>
   <Name>Sam</Name>
</Response>
```

When I use the same code for this, I am not getting any output or error.

Depends on the user's input, I get either the type 1 xml or type 2 xml as ouput. For the both the case I need to extract the "name" element value.
If it is more than one element with the same name then comma separate the values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `css` instead of `xpath`, this will work for you,

```
 doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body) 

 values  =  doc.css('Name').select{|name|  name.text}.join','

 puts values
 => Ram,Sam
```